# Picking out a specific column in a table

Tags: python, astronomy

My goal is to import a table of astrophysical data that I have saved to my computer (obtained from matching 2 other tables in TOPCAT, if you know it), and extract certain relevant columns. I hope to then do further manipulations on these columns. I am a complete beginner in python, so I apologise for basic errors. I've done my best to try and solve my problem on my own but I'm a bit lost.

This script I have written so far:

```
import pandas as pd
input_file = "location\\filename"
dataset = pd.read_csv(input_file,skiprows=12,usecols=[1])
```

The file that I'm trying to import is listed as having file type "File", in my drive. I've looked at this file in Notepad and it has a lot of descriptive bumf in the first few rows, so to try and get rid of this I've used "skiprows" as you can see. The data in the file is separated column-wise by lines--at least that's how it appears in Notepad.

The problem is when I try to extract the first column using "usecol" it instead returns what appears to be the first row in the command window, as well as a load of vertical bars between each value. I assume it is somehow not interpreting the table correctly? Not understanding what's a column and what's a row.

**What I've tried:** Modifying the file and saving it in a different filetype. This gives the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory: 'location\\filename'
```

Despite the fact that the new file is saved in exactly the same location.

I've tried using "pd.read_table" instead of csv, but this doesn't seem to change anything (nor does it give me an error).

When I've tried to extract multiple columns (ie "usecol=[1,2]") I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: \[1, 2\]
```

My hope is that someone with experience can give some insight into what's likely going on to cause these problems.

Comment: the file needs to be names correctly:  `input_file = "location\\filename"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybie you can try `dataset.iloc[:,0]` . With iloc you can extract the column or line you want by index(not only). [:,0] for all the lines of 1st column.

Comment: I tried this and it returns me the 1st row (I understand it's supposed to return the first column). I tried reversing the order "[0,:]" and it still returns the first row! Any other integer in place of "0" gives me `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`. But my table has more than one column so it shouldn't be a problem. Does this give any clues to what's happened?

Answer (score 0):

The file is incorrectly named.

I expect that you are reading a `csv` file or an `xlsx` or `txt` file. So the (windows) path would look similar to this:

```py
import pandas as pd
input_file = "C:\\python\\tests\\test_csv.csv"
dataset = pd.read_csv(input_file,skiprows=12,usecols=[1])
```

The error message tell you this:
`No such file or directory: 'location\\filename'`

Comment: Thanks, I specified ".txt" in the filename and I no longer get the error you mentioned. The other problems still remain, however.

Comment: glad to have helped.  if you post the other problems along with **an example of the text file**, then we can help. It would be better as a *new question* given that this question is answered.